# What determines default Interactive Report column display in Oracle APEX 5?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I have an Interactive Report page in Oracle APEX 5 that includes a SQL Query with ~15 columns or so.
When I first load the report, the columns are in a certain order, and columns are set to Do Not Display (as seen under `Actions`-> `Select Columns`).

All the columns have the property `Type` as `Plain Text` and none has a condition defined in the `Page Designer`, under `{Page Name}` -> `Regions` -> `Content Body` -> `{Interactive Report}` -> `Columns`.

My Interactive Report has a dynamic query under a APEX_COLLECTION and the end user doesn't have developer privilegies.

My question is, what determines which columns are set to `Do Not Display` and those set to `Display in Report`?

Comment: Here's what I noticed: when I create an IR and run it for the first time, all columns are displayed. However, when I add another columns, they aren't displayed so I have to do it manually (under Actions -> Select Columns). I tried to do that on apex.oracle.com, but - it runs Apex 18 and I didn't notice such a behavior so - maybe they *fixed* the issue ...

Comment: In my case the first run doesn't show some columns like you described. The problem is a little bit different.

Answer (score 4):

When you *first* create an Interactive Report, all the columns will be present in the Designer under the Columns list and in the order in which they appear in the `SELECT` statement. When you run the page, the IR will display all the columns.

If you edit the SQL behind that IR to add columns, any new columns will appear at the end of the Columns list. You will have to run the page, select Actions > Select Columns, and add them to the displayed list of columns to have them display. You'll probably want to then select Actions > Save Report as the primary default report to have them displayed by default for your users.

Comment: In my case the first run doesn't show some columns like you described. The problem is a little bit different.